# java networking: how to get server's IP :

Tags: java

i want to make a chat messenger with java which is going to work on a LAN local network.
in client i have:

```
Socket socket=new Socket(serverIP, port);
```

how to understand what is serverIP, the ip address of the computer on which the serverSocket is waiting for an incoming connection

this is a really small network: 1 server and 1 client, a cross cable network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't want to practice network programming, it's a real program and is going to be commercial. but anyhow only 2 computers are going to be in the network via cross cable. as the program is going to be installed on different computers, the server's IP is surly unknown to me while i'm programming and can not be predefined. now i'm searching for a way that my program it's self can find the server's IP in that local network and can connect to the server. so it can not be passed to the client via argument, as it is unknown and the program MUST find that...i finally found 2 great ways for java program to automatically find it's server Host Name and the user is not going to give the program any IP or any information...

1.first of all we find our local host name:

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
```

then we run this command line:

```
net view
```

this returns the name of hosts currently in the network(LAN network in my situation), now as we have our local host name and all host names, we can find the other host (which is definitely the server in my situation, as there are only 2 computers in the network...) name and so easily connect to that:

```
Socket socket=new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_NAME),port);
```

2.the clients also can get the server's IP via multicastSocketing. all clients and server join to a group on a predefined IP and the server sends it's IP to all receivers(= clients).

Answer (score 2):

The client *must know* the server IP - it must be predefined. There is no magic way the client can find it out. So you can:

- hardcode the server IP in the client code
- pass the server IP as command line argument when running the client

If your LAN router has [DHCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) set up, your IP addresses will change over time so the second variant is better. I suppose that commercial chat clients have a well known URL/IP hardcoded or similar from which they obtain the chat server adresses.

In [this C# example](http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-chat-server-programming.htm)  this problem is bypassed by running both on the same machine, but you can see that the client has the "server IP" hardcoded.

In [this VB example](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-make-a-simple-chat-program-in-visual-basic-/step7/Using-the-programConclusion/) the IP is being entered by the user.

EDIT:

The client [Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) (as you wrote it) connects to the server [ServerSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html). The ServerSocket knows the client Socket IP address because the client just connected to it from that IP address! If you don't understand this, read (and **try by yourself**) this [excellent tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html).

"Pass it as an argument":

Let' say you have a folder named "project", and inside it a folder named "mypackage" and inside it a file named HelloWorld.class. HelloWorld.class is a Java class file compiled from HelloWorld.java, a Java source file which looks like this:

```
package mypackage;

public class HelloWorld {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("You entered the following arguments from the command line:");
    for (int i = 0; i< args.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(args[i]);
    }
}
```

place yourself in the project directory and write:

```
java mypackage.HelloWorld commandlineArgument1 commandlineArgument2
```

it will print:

```
You entered the following arguments from the command line:
commandlineArgument1
commandlineArgument2
```

A [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) for this.

Comment: the client and server are not on the same machines, and there is also no router (cross cable network). as you said, the server's IP is not constant and varies from one network to another(maybe the IP is assigned automatically by windows or maybe the user defines it manually...) and CAN NOT be predefined. so what should i do?

Comment: this is not a NEW problem, how is it solved in such client server chat messengers ????

Comment: could you please tell me what you mean by " pass it as an argument" ? how ? I think you mean that the server sends it's IP to the client, then there is another problem, what is the client's IP so that we can send message to ?!!!!! however i think i didn't get what u mean...

Comment: this is a really small network: 1 server and 1 client, a cross cable network

Comment: thank you, but my problem is not still solved!!! why? because the problem is in the first line:"The client Socket (as you wrote it) connects to the server ServerSocket" my socket doesn't know the serverSocket's IP, and so can not connect !!!!!

Comment: what do you mean by "so *can not* connect"? have you tried it? when you start the server and the client is there some exception thrown - if so pls post? have you tried out and red the socket tutorial?

Comment: if it does not solve your problem don't accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

The socket class is for a client, so this would be the IP of the server you are connecting to.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html

Comment: ok, how to know what is the server's IP?

Comment: Ask the people providing the service.  Usually you use a hostname like `www.stackoverflow.com` rather than an IP address.

Comment: @db I suggest using links from Java 7. ;)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey could you please provide link for "links from Java 7."?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, a very great idea: " Usually you use a hostname like www.stackoverflow.com rather than an IP address", but now i must have the server host name and that is some thing constant, but how to get that?

Comment: @soheil.mernoosh And the people providing the service can't tell you?

Comment: "the people that provide service", which service do u mean?